# OleDbDataReader only reads 29,991 of 95,526 records

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I'm using an `OleDbDataReader`, but it only reads 29,991 of 95,526 records:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [data$]", connection);
using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        c++;
        row1Col0 = dr[0].ToString();

    }
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Why doesn't it read all records?

Comment: Did you have a try/catch block around this code? Did you catch the exception (if any) and show a message on video?

Comment: So what actually happens? Does it give an error? Or does the `dr.Read()` call actually return false as if there is no more data?

Comment: Well just because **95,526 - 29,991 = 65,535**, I suppose there might be an overflow somewhere with a 16-bit integer on the way.

Comment: i use try/catch block but it not throws any exception,

Comment: i use 32 bit integer but result is same , it doesn't give any error it simply prints the result

Comment: The database server is Oracle?